# android tabs allCaps works only for first tab

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, material-components-android

I'm trying to set my tabs text textAllCaps to false.

For some reason only firs tab has needed results, but the second is still all caps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAMAy.jpg

I've set tabTextAppearance to MyCustomTextAppearance and in styles two attributes are set to textAllCaps, android:textAllCaps are set to false

activity:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />
```

in styles:

```
    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

in Java:

```
public class NewLoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        RegisterFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public ActivityNewLoginBinding binding;
    private List<String> titles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_new_login);
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        setToolBarTitle(getSupportActionBar(), getResources().getString(R.string.login_action_title));
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);      // Disable the button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // Remove the left caret
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // Remove the icon
        }

        binding.tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        binding.tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        titles.add(getString(R.string.login_action_title));
        titles.add(getString(R.string.regi));
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        LoginTabAdapter tabAdapter;
        tabAdapter = new LoginTabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, titles);

        binding.viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
        binding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        binding.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPager);

        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("signup")) {
            binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
    }
```